# AWS Cognito SDK on Android, Login Crashes with parameter cognitoDevice Null

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-cognito

So I ran into this funky issue when using AWS Cognito's SDK on Android,
but with Kotlin instead of JAVA.

I am attempting to login, and it seems when it reaches the success function of the AuthenticationHandler, it crashes.

```
 override fun onSuccess(cognitoUserSession: CognitoUserSession, cognitoDevice: CognitoDevice?) {
            // Sign-in was successful, cognitoUserSession will contain tokens for the user
```

The Error It Crashes with:

```
EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter cognitoDevice
```

In other words stating that cognitoDevice is null? but it Shouldnt be? I am working right off of AWS documentation, which is in JAVA and im thinking this might be a Kotlin specific error. I've already tried adding another onSuccess fun  that doesnt take the cognitoDevice as a parameter to no Success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of scratching my head on this issue, the solution was too simple and the issue was that the code did not translate directly from Java to Kotlin well.

As other people are bound to run into the same issue if they follow the tutorial on the Amazon web services website, I decided to share the solution so a quick search can find it.

We need to add a "?" to the CognitoDevices because Kotlin by nature avoids nulls, but since this code is originally in Java it passes in a null.

```
 override fun onSuccess(cognitoUserSession: CognitoUserSession, cognitoDevice: CognitoDevice?) {
            // Sign-in was successful, cognitoUserSession will contain 
        }
```